# Evaluate the indefinite integral $\int \frac{ \sqrt{x+1} }{x} \,\mathrm dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I can solve derivatives up to second order and started to learn integration recently, and I have learnt the basic formulae and method of substitutions.

I'm now stuck in this problem:
$$\int \frac{ \sqrt{x+1} }{x} \,\mathrm dx.$$

[image: image of my work]

Comment: Also plz teach me to use proper math format codes for stackexchange

Comment: Here's my suggested edit (no need for that first and last paragraphs): `I can solve derivatives up to second order and started to learn integration recently, have learnt the basic formulae and method of substitutions.

Am now stuck in this problem:

$$\int \frac{ \sqrt{x+1} }{x} \,\mathrm dx.$$` $\quad$ Unfortunately, your question will be quickly deleted if you don't show your efforts and be more specific about what you're struggling with.

Comment: What exactly did you try? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: i substituted √(x+1) = t.  Now dt/dx = 1/2√(x+1)=1/2t      Hence the integrand becomes 2t²/(t²-1). then i substituted (t²-1) by u but the same result comes and i am stuck

Comment: Show your work in the question. What happened when you did that substitution?

Comment: I dont know the proper format to write but i am trying

Comment: [mathjax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We continue from OP's work in the comments, wherein the substitution $$x = t^2 - 1, \qquad dx = 2 t \,dt$$ transforms the integral to
$$2 \int\frac{t^2 \,dt}{t^2 - 1}.$$

**Hint** We can rearrange our integrand as
$$2 \int\left(1 - \frac{1}{1 - t^2}\right)dt .$$

> Integrating each term gives $$2(t - \operatorname{artanh} t) + C .$$

Alternatively, we can apply the method of partial fractions to write the integral in $t$ as
$$\int \left(2 - \frac{1}{t + 1} + \frac{1}{t - 1}\right) dt .$$

Comment: THANKS!(1)how you integrated the second term is still unclear to me Perhaps I have to go forward through my text book for this (2) what is artanh t  again I think I have to study more but Thanks

Comment: You're welcome. If you're not familiar with $\operatorname{artanh}$, we can apply the method of partial fractions to rewrite the integral in $t$ as $$\int \left(2 - \frac{1}{t + 1} + \frac{1}{t - 1}\right) \,dt.$$ (You might know $\operatorname{artanh} t$ better as $\frac{1}{2} \log \frac{1 + t}{1 - t}$.)